# Office application hangs during document opening via interop

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, office-interop

I am trying to open a file but the Office application hangs during document opening in VB.NET.

I have this code:

```
Dim oProp As Object
Dim strPropValue As String
Dim lngRetVal As Integer
Dim strmsg As String
Dim lngretcode As Integer
Dim strPropertyName As String

Dim oWordDoc As Word.Document

Dim ObjOfficeAPP As Object

ObjOfficeAPP = New Word.Application()

GetWORDKEYS = cstFAILURE

ObjOfficeAPP.DisplayAlerts = WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsAll
ObjOfficeAPP.Application.Visible = True

oWordDoc = ObjOfficeAPP.Documents.Open(FileName:=strpFileName, Visible:=False)
```

I have problems on the line:

```
oWordDoc = ObjOfficeAPP.Documents.Open(FileName:=strpFileName, Visible:=False)
```

The debugger hangs on the Documents.Open() call, and just stays there waiting - without firing any type of exception or error. We have looked in the event log but only found the following.

My problem is, how can I set to open this document and not to block on the line with the `Documents.Open()` call?

Comment: If you set `Visible:=True`, does any error message appear?

Comment: @AndrewMorton doesn't appear anything.

Comment: Have you made sure, in Windows Task Manager, that there are no instances of Word running which might be interfering with what you want to do?

Comment: @AndrewMorton when I'm on the line ObjOfficeAPP = New Word.Application() into Task Manager open a winword.exe file, but I don't see anything else. And if I close this process my code continue to going. But if I don't set end process to winword.exe my code stay block.

Comment: Can you use `Dim ObjOfficeAPP = New Word.Application()` instead of putting it on one line, *and* put [`Option Strict On`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) as the first line of the code, before any `Imports` or anything else. It may show some mistakes which need to be corrected.

Comment: What happens if you try to open that document as a user - can Word open it? Do you get any messages / requests for some kind of confirmation? If you try a different document in your code, does that work? Is the string value in strpFileName contain a local or a network path?

Comment: Where and when do you try to automate Word? Is it a windows service or any server app?

Answer (score 0):

Here are few points that could help:

1. Don't use the `Application` property for setting the `Visible` property:

   `ObjOfficeAPP.Visible = True`
2. Don't set the `DisplayAlerts` property before opening a document.
3. Use the `System.Reflection.Missing.Value` for missing arguments.

You may find the [How to automate Word from Visual Basic .NET to create a new document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/316383/how-to-automate-word-from-visual-basic-net-to-create-a-new-document) article helpful which explains the required steps for automating Word and provides a sample code:

```
 'Start Word and open the document template.
 oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
 oWord.Visible = True
 oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add
```